# Getting 404 not found when trying to delete Azure blob

Tags: c#, azure

I am getting a list of files hosted in Azure and attempting to delete them.

```
var blobList = container.ListBlobs(prefix: "/2017/1/", useFlatBlobListing:true);
foreach (var blob in blobList)
{
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blob.Uri.ToString());
    blockBlob.Delete(); // This line causes a 404 not found exception.
}
```

When I debug and step through the code the blob.Uri matches the folder structure in Azure so not sure why this exception occurs.

Edit: Found an answer - I have to check the type and box appropriately

```
foreach (var item in blobList)
{
    if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
    {
        CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
        blob.Delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you make the last part an answer?

Comment: Echoing what @EJoshuaS stated: don't place your solution in the question. Place it in its own answer. This way, this question can be properly closed out.

Answer (score 1):

The op wrote:

> Edit: Found an answer - I have to check the type and box appropriately
>
> ```
> foreach (var item in blobList)
> {
>     if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
>     {
>         CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
>         blob.Delete();
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: [Answered in a question edit and converted to a community wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que)